# How to compile multiple python files into single .exe file using pyarmor?

Tags: python, pack, pyarmor

How to compile multiple python files into single .exe file using pyarmor? 
I am currently using: 
`pyarmor pack --clean -e "--onefile " file.py` but it work only for one file :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `--recursive` argument, which will recursively look in all the py files you have in a dir and obfuscate them.

`pyarmor pack --clean -e "--onefile " -x " --recursive" entry.py`

`entry.py` must be your entry script, which means the file you execute.